# Convert Single<Single<Data>> to Single<Data> in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2

I am fetching value from 2 database tables and after duplicate removal,  based on them fetching from third table.
My sample code is :

```
db.select("SELECT id from table1 ")
            .getAs(String.class)
            .collectInto(new HashSet<String>(), HashSet::add)
            .zipWith(db.select("SELECT id from table2 ")
                    .getAs(String.class)
                    .collectInto(new HashSet<String>(), HashSet::add),new BiFunction<Set,Set, Single<HashSet<String>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Single<HashSet<String>> apply(Set t1, Set t2) throws Exception {
                            t1.addAll(t2);

                            return db.select("select useful_data from table3 where id IN ("+AsQuatedString(t1)+").getAs(String.class).collectInto(new HashSet<String>(), HashSet::add);
                        }
                    })/*Point A*/.subscribe(a -> a.subscribe(b -> System.out.println(b)));
```

So the problem is at [Point A] I am getting `Single<Single<HashSet>>` which I cannot give as response to rest client.

How to convert it to `Single<HashSet>`.

Using [this](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava2-jdbc) for DB connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your zip with should return a `Single<HashSet>` with a merged set and then you can put your second database request in `flatmap`.

```
db.select("SELECT id from table1 ")
        .getAs(String.class)
        .collectInto(new HashSet<String>(), HashSet::add)
        .zipWith(db.select("SELECT id from table2 ")
                .getAs(String.class)
                .collectInto(new HashSet<String>(), HashSet::add), (t1, t2) -> {
                    t1.addAll(t2);
                    return t1;
                })
        .flatMap(concatSet -> {
            // concatSet is a HashMap<String>
            return db.select("select useful_data from table3 where id IN ("+AsQuatedString(concatSet)+")
                    .getAs(String.class)
                    .collectInto(new HashSet<String>(), HashSet::add);
        })
        .subscribe(b -> { // b is a HashMap<String>, result of your second db request.
            System.out.println(b);
        });
```